# Image exporting in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I used the code Export.image.toDrive () to export photos to Google Drive but got an error.

Answer (score 2):

`ee.Image.reduceToVectors` converts an image to features, so its return value is a `FeatureCollection`. You cannot export a `FeatureCollection` using `Export.image` because a `FeatureCollection` is not an `Image`.

If you want an image where the features have been drawn, then use `ee.Image.paint` after `reduceToVectors`. (It requires an image, which is the "background" for the painting; you can use an `ee.Image.constant` for a solid background, or the original image if you want the features drawn on top of it.

If you want to export the actual computed features then you must use `Export.table` instead of `Export.image`. “Table” is another name for a `FeatureCollection`. Tables can be exported in CSV, shapefile, KML, GeoJSON, or stored as an Earth Engine asset for further use (`Export.table.toAsset`).